# Solve blocking http python function through Asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am implementing a blockchain that communicates through http requests ([inspired by this blogpost](https://hackernoon.com/learn-blockchains-by-building-one-117428612f46)). This blockchain has a proof of work method, that, depending on the difficulty, can block other http requests for quite some time. This is why I am trying to implement the new `asyncio` features from python. The following works:

```
async def proof_of_work(self, last_proof):
    """
    Simple Proof of Work Algorithm:
     - Find a number p' such that hash(pp') contains leading 4 zeroes, where p is the previous p'
    """
    proof = 0
    while self.valid_proof(last_proof, proof) is False:
        proof += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    return proof
```

However, this makes my proof of work extremely slow, I guess this is because it is forced to sleep after each iteration. What would be a more elegant way to fix this?

```
    while self.valid_proof(last_proof, proof) is False:
        proof += 1
        if proof % 1000 == 0:
             await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Would quicken it all up a bit, but it looks a bit dirty. What would be the correct way to implement this?

Comment: Run CPU-intensive code in a thread using  [asyncio.run_in_excutor](https://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/threads.html)

Comment: Does `self.valid_proof(...)` use blocking IOs (HTTP requests, ...). If yes, you should "async" this method and use `asyncio` compatible code inside.

Comment: You can also decrease your sleep time. You don’t actually need to sleep here; you just want to make the loop gives other tasks a chance to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run CPU-blocking code inside coroutine, you should run it in separate execution flow (to avoid asyncio's event loop freezing) using `run_in_executor()`.

You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` if you just want another execution flow or (I think better) to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` to delegate CPU related work to other core(s).

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import hashlib


# ORIGINAL VERSION:
# https://github.com/dvf/blockchain/blob/master/blockchain.py
def valid_proof(last_proof, proof):
    guess = f'{last_proof}{proof}'.encode()
    guess_hash = hashlib.sha256(guess).hexdigest()
    return guess_hash[:4] == "0000"


def proof_of_work(last_proof):
    proof = 0
    while valid_proof(last_proof, proof) is False:
        proof += 1
    return proof


# ASYNC VERSION:
async def async_proof_of_work(last_proof):
    proof = await loop.run_in_executor(_executor, proof_of_work, last_proof)
    return proof


async def main():
    proof = await async_proof_of_work(0)
    print(proof)


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    _executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(4)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```

**Output:**

```
69732
```